# jQuery: list of strings. How to count the non-empty ones?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of strings like so, some are empty and some have values on them:

```
var search_criteria1 = getParameterByName('search_criteria1[]');
var search_criteria2 = getParameterByName('search_criteria2[]');
var search_criteria3 = getParameterByName('search_criteria3[]');
var search_criteria4 = getParameterByName('search_criteria4[]');
```

I would like to go over them and display a small message, counting only the ones with some value on them, something like so: "you searched for 3 criteria".

How can I accomplish this?

I am using jQuery. Many thanks,

Comment: Are you asking how to see if a string is empty, how to create a collection  of strings, how to filter a collection of strings, how to not hardcode the string variables, or…? What specific issue are you having?

Comment: The idea is to find how many variables are not empty and display the result.

Comment: Right; I’m asking what the specific issue is. In other words what part of the problem is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would loop through them, or if I need to "group" them first. I'm also unsure if I should check if they are "null" or "undefined", and finally I don't know how to create a sum (+1) for each of them that has a value assigned... so muy doubts are multiple!

Comment: Hi, do you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zn14gcy6/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it working:

```
var array = [post1, post2, post3, post4, post5, post6, post7, post8, post9, post10];
var count = 0;
$.each(array, function( index, value ) {
  //alert( index + ": " + value );
  if(value !== null && value !== ''  && value !== undefined)
    {
       count++;
    }else{
      
    }
    
});

alert(`You searched for ${count} criteria.`)
```